Custom font when printing out to the terminal
For a college project, we have the requirement to create a CLI-Project. We are not allowed to use third-party-libraries. I decided to create a chess game and want to print the board for every move. For the pieces, I want to use a custom font, but I don't know how to use it. All questions/tutorials are about JavaFX/Swing

That will almost certainly be impossible without native code

The best way is to use a custom console, but you are not allowed to use libraries, and so I would stick with the console's standard font.

A workaround would be to determine which of your terminal's fonts have chess piece glyphs and give instructions of how to set that to run your code. If you're really lucky, the default might have them

Another possibility is to just use letters for chess pieces, like "p" pawn "Q" queen, and print that way.  If you're really ambitious you could add some "ascii art" to the output, but I'd get the whole thing working before attempting that.

@MarcePuente The problem statement says that the CLI (command line interface) will be used.  I assume that's a requirement he can't change.

I asked chat gpt and it gave me the suggestion to use unicode symbols.

You don’t need a custom font.  There are already characters for chess pieces:  '\u2654', '\u2655', '\u2656', '\u2657', '\u2658', '\u2659', '\u265a', '\u265b', '\u265c', '\u265d', '\u265e', and '\u265f'.  (In a Windows command window, I had to use chcp 65001 before running in order to get the characters to display.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode

Bonus: Get fancy with Box Drawing Unicode characters.

Related: this and this
